# Internal Server Error (MAC OSX) when use dotnet run

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware [0] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request System.InvalidOperationException: Can not find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' 
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()

And the stack reads:

> InvalidOperationException: Can not find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App'
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator.MoveNext()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature(TFeature feature)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.GetCompilationReferences()
>   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func valueFactory)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo fileInfo, string compilationContent)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.CreateCacheEntry(string relativePath, string normalizedPath, Func compile)
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.GetOrAdd(string relativePath, Func compile)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(string relativePath)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet expirationTokens, string relativePath, bool isMainPage)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, string pageName, bool isMainPage)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+d__26.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__32.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__31.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__29.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__23.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__18.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware+d__5.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()

Show raw exception details

Comment: To format the table/code/error correctly, please add **4 leading** space to each line of the table. Also, this question has very low quality. Please review [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a question.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6318